# how to display/print class method in python

Tags: python, class, printing, display

I just learned Python, I want to ask something..
For example, I have code

```
import pandas as pd

class Prep:

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Prep, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.data_frame = pd.read_csv('data_manual.csv', sep=';')

    def raw(self):
        self.rawInput = self.data_frame.iloc[:, 1:8]
        self.rawTarget = self.data_frame.iloc[:, 8]
        return self.rawInput, self.rawTarget
```

I've tried

```
test = Prep (). raw ()
print (test)
```

its display `rawInput` and `rawTarget`

but what I want to show is only one of them

how to display `rawInput` only not both

Comment: Why did you return both if you only want one of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to display rawInput only not both

Just remove `self.rawTarget` from return

```
def raw(self):
    self.rawInput = self.data_frame.iloc[:, 1:8]
    self.rawTarget = self.data_frame.iloc[:, 8]
    return self.rawInput
```

or try this

```
test = Prep().raw()
print(test[0])
```

Comment: Is there no other way, without changing `return`?

Comment: @riokuroky, I added this option to my answer, use `print(test[0])`